# Do I need to write a custom session class for CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I cannot seem to get CI's session library to function the way I want it to. Essentially, I am storing 2 different categories of data within the sessions. The data within the 2 categories may contain the same value. Right now my attempt to add a key => value pair to the session is failing, as it is only allowing 1 key => value pair to be associated with the array. It overrides itself each time I do a post.

```
$arr = array(
    'favorite_products' => array(),
    'viewed_products' => array()
    );


$arr["favorite_products"][] = $fav_id;


$this->session->set_userdata($arr);
```

This is what the array looks when I `print_r` it:

```
Array ( [favorite_products] => Array ( [4f1066c2b7fff] => 1648406 ) [viewed_products] => Array ( ))
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this just the way CI's session library works?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Array ( [favorite_products] => Array ( [0] => 1648406 [1] => 0000000 )There isn't a limit to how many fav products a user can have.

Comment: add another `$arr["favorite_products"][] = 0333` and update your output, looks like you're still showing the `uniqueid()` output

Comment: also, destroy your session, before making further attempts.

Comment: @jondavidjohn I'll try that. I've destroyed the session too.

Comment: The second $arr['favorire_products'][] = '0333' worked

Comment: So did my answer fix your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are destroying your session between attempts, but this code should work just fine...

```
$arr = array(
    'favorite_products' => array(),
    'viewed_products' => array()
    );


$arr["favorite_products"][] = $fav_id;
$arr["favorite_products"][] = 033333; // another id


$this->session->set_userdata($arr);
```

should give you...

```
Array ( 
    [favorite_products] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1648406, 
        [1] => 033333 
    ),
    [viewed_products] => Array ()
)
```

If you are trying to do this between requests...

```
// if it doesn't already exist in the session, create an empty array.
if( ! ($favorite_products = $this->session->get_userdata("favorite_products")))
{
    $favorite_products = array();
}

$favorite_products[] = "new id or info";

$this->session->set_userdata("favorite_products", $favorite_products);
```